# If / else function doesn't get fully executed, only the else line

Tags: python, if-statement

```py
question = input ('ready/pass').upper() 

if question == 'ready':
   print ('Okay, let's go!)
elif question == 'pass':
   print ('Sad to see you go...')
   quit() 
else:
   print ("Sorry, I don't understand ")
```

Comment: Are you aware what `upper() ` does? try `lower()` instead.

Comment: Why are using quit()?

Comment: Because after 'pass' the program should end, is that wrong?

Comment: @GiGiGem, i think he/she meant that in provided code sample `quit()` call is quite useless unless `quit()` does some finalization.

Answer (score 2):

```py
question = input('ready/pass').lower()

if question == 'ready':
   print ("Okay, let's go!")
elif question == 'pass':
   print ('Sad to see you go...')
   quit() 
else:
   print("Sorry, I don't understand ")
```

You should use [`str.lower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) instead of [`str.upper()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper).

```py
"reADy / PASs".upper()  # => READY / PASS
"reADy / PASs".lower()  # => ready / pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You are changing your input ready or pass to uppercase but in your condition you are checking with lowercase.